# Codename one set next Textfield to be focused

Tags: codenameone

I'm new using codename one, i need set the order how the textfields will be focus

http://i.prntscr.com/9c5f0a08fe214d639fc09f228bf814db.png

the user fill the field "telefono fijo"(Homephone). When the user press the next key(red circle), the focus is going down to the "Correo electronico"(email) textfield instead to the "celular" textfield.

How can I handled the focus direction after key next was pressed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next button is moving the focus from the textfield.getNextFocusDown() method, you can use the setNextFocusDown on your TextField to modify the default behavior

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, i was trying with set NextFocusRight but in somewhere i read that functions are only for non touch keyboard, so i discard the others, my bad!